# how to watch javascript execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

is there any tool available to watch how browser  renders javascript  ?

consider  some x website using  angular/jquery . I want to find which functions are being called E2E without using  chrome/firefox debugging tools . I tried  using profile , but it don't  give clear picture .

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What exactly do you want do you want to watch? I hardly read that you'd like to break at every function that manipulates (add/change/remove nodes) the DOM? Is this right? Why don't you want to use the browsers debugger for this? How should this process be displayed if not using the debugger (how should it look like)?

Comment: I want to watch the execution  flow ,  consider   I am browsing some X  website (ex Google ), I want to  know  which javascript  is being called  onload , and which JS  functions are  handling DOM  stuff  ..etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about watching but you can see the end result.  Firefox has the (Web) [Developers Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/?src=search). Pull-down View Source -> View Generated source.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a `console.log()` to the functions that you would like to know when they are called. Then to see when they are being called, on your website go to the console in developer tools (`ctrl+shift+j` in chrome) and it will show when each function is called.

e.g.

```
function abc(paramater1) {
  //do something
  console.log("function abc() called");
}
function xyz(paramaterA) {
  //do something
  console.log("function xyz() called");
}
```

Then open up chrome console (`ctrl+shift+j`) and when, for example, `function xyz()` is called, it will tell you so.